# Loop iteration - check if no items are yielded

Tags: ruby

I have a function, which yields few items. I'm iterating them using

```
my_function() do |item|
  ... some code here ...
end
```

Is there a cool way to check if the iterator doesn't return any items? Something like:

```
my_function() do |item|
  ... some code here ...
else
  puts "No items found"
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby best practice : if not empty each do else in one operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860310/ruby-best-practice-if-not-empty-each-do-else-in-one-operator)

Comment: @sawa Though that question is pretty heavily steeped in performing the action within Haml, where certain constructs cannot by used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually functions that iterate return the enumerable (e.g. array) that was iterated. If you do this, you can test if this return value is empty:

```
if my_function(){ |item| … }.empty?
  puts "nothing found!"
end
```

Of course, if your block is on multiple lines it may make more sense to write this as:

```
items = my_function() do |item|
  # …
end
puts "Nothing found!" if items.empty?
```

If it's not easy or efficient for you to create an enumerable that you iterated, then you simply need to modify your function to return a boolean at the end indicating if you iterated anything.

Comment: This is the right way to go. And it is the same as my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860310). I wonder why I got two downvotes whereas this answer got three upvotes (including one from me).

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the return of the iteration to a variable, and then compare it to anything.

```
result = myfunction() do |item|
  # some code here ...
end
if result.empty?
  puts "Something"
end
```